# Erro Json org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character

Tags: android, json

Não estou conseguindo achar o erro na hora que pegar este json

http://www.sinestandar.com.br/maker/sugeridos.txt

olha oque está saindo no log

```
12-19 13:39:53.589    9554-9564/json.exemplo.com.cortecabelo E/DEVMEDIA﹕ Erro no parsing do JSON
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 280 of { "AplicativosSugeridos" : [
{ "nome": "Chegou a Hora", "icone": "https://lh4.ggpht.com/IQ4km0WoDCIB-6ESZLzSYGYOae5X-ZDUKAdmB3D4_i7KF8HhVuWu65cpcxUOTDNH8tI=w300-rw" , "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilgner.chegouahora&hl=pt_BR },
{ "nome": "IMC Calc", "icone": "https://lh6.ggpht.com/VoNa54hKxdX6U47rrTlZ72ngPMFAcvTY38ugnifRsXSQJzAwprJDSZB25uBTHQoEbP8=w300-rw" , "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilgner.imc1&hl=pt_BR }
]
}
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:390)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:96)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:426)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:99)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:381)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:96)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
        at json.exemplo.com.cortecabelo.BaixarSugestoes.getSugestoes(BaixarSugestoes.java:70)
        at json.exemplo.com.cortecabelo.BaixarSugestoes.doInBackground(BaixarSugestoes.java:57)
        at json.exemplo.com.cortecabelo.BaixarSugestoes.doInBackground(BaixarSugestoes.java:27)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Codigo

```
@Override
protected List<Sugestoes> doInBackground(String... params) {
    String urlString = params[0];
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlString);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String json = toString(instream);
            instream.close();
            List<Sugestoes> sugestoes = getSugestoes(json);
            return sugestoes;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DEVMEDIA", "Falha ao acessar Web service", e);
    }
    return null;
}

private List<Sugestoes> getSugestoes(String jsonString) {

    List<Sugestoes> sugestoes = new ArrayList<Sugestoes>();
    try {
        JSONObject trendLists = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jArray = trendLists.getJSONArray("AplicativosSugeridos");

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            Sugestoes sugestao = new Sugestoes();
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            sugestao.nome = json_data.getString("nome");
            sugestao.link = json_data.getString("link");
            sugestao.icone = json_data.getString("icone");
            String nomeArquivo=baixarImagem(sugestao.icone, "imagemSugestao" + i);
            sugestao.icone = nomeArquivo;
            Banco banco = new Banco(context);
            if(banco.insertS(sugestao)){
                Log.d("Resultado S","Salvou");
            }else{
                Log.d("Resultado S","Nao Salvou");
            }
            sugestoes.add(sugestao);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("DEVMEDIA", "Erro no parsing do JSON", e);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sugestoes;
}
```

Comment: Seus URLs dentro dos objetos estão sem o fechamento das aspas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu segundo link não está fechado como string.

```
"nome": "Chegou a Hora",
"icone":
"https://lh4.ggpht.com/IQ4km0WoDCIB-6ESZLzSYGYOae5X-ZDUKAdmB3D4_i7KF8HhVuWu65cpcxUOTDNH8tI=w300-rw",
"link":
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilgner.chegouahora&hl=pt_BR  <- Cade o fechamento das aspas!?
```

Comment: no que burrice kkkk , obrigado nem tinha visto

Comment: Não é burrice, na pressa, você esquece uma coisa ou outra e fica pensando "mas que diabos ta dando errado? ta tudo correto!".

Aconteceu comigo de enviar um JSON com uma lista pra preencher uma tabela. Numa das funções, ela estava correta, mas na outra não estava e eu não entendia porque. Até que eu vi que o que a tabela estava recebendo não era uma lista... haha

Comment: e kk , tava doido aqui porque usei o mesmo código para recuperar outro json tava aqui olhando oque tava errado kk